# Do not show expired results on my mysqli query

Tags: mysql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM courses WHERE course_all = '1' AND course_hour = 'inactive' 
AND (cdate > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 1 HOUR) AND course_hour = 'active');
```

This query is supposed to display all results except the results that have `course_hour = 'active'` and expired by one hours.

**What i want:**

I want display all results that have `course_all = '1'`, `course_hour = 'inactive'` and the results that have `course_hour='active'` but created recently and do not bypass one hours since created.

Comment: What is cdate ?

Comment: Why are you using -1 Hour? if you want to subtract you can use DATE_SUB()

Comment: cdate is timestamp, yes you are right date_sub is same as what i did.

Comment: can you please add some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your query to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM courses 
WHERE course_all = '1' AND 
(course_hour = 'inactive' 
OR (course_hour = 'active' AND cdate > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 1 HOUR)));
```

Comment: This not solved the problem, the results expired all time displayed.

Comment: The problem come from: `cdate > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 1 HOUR)` i tried to show all that not expired with this only on the request, but nothing shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT * FROM courses 
WHERE course_all = '1' AND 
(course_hour = 'inactive' 
OR (course_hour = 'active' AND cdate > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)));
```

Comment: NOW(), CURDATE(), curr_timestamp all same thing.

Comment: CURDATE() will give current date while NOW() will give full date time.

Comment: Yes, i tried it but didn't worked, same thing ... i think it's related to server configuration (timezone) ... or column type.

Comment: Try changing the type of cdate to DATETIME

Comment: Same thing, i tried too a different approch like: `NOW() < DATE_ADD(cdate, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)` everytime same ...

Comment: @JisMaxi Any progress?

Comment: The request was right from the first ... problem is on the timezone of apache configuration.

Comment: @JisMaxi OK :+1